# click_action de push notification android não funciona

Tags: java, android, push-notification

Ola.

Estou tentando fazer uma ação para meu push notification, mas quando eu recebo esse push, ele não direciona pra tela que eu quero... quando eu coloco esse getAction(), pelo contrário, buga meu push e não abre a tela.

Segue me código

Dentro do Android Manifest

```
 <service
        android:name=".Configs.push.PushNotificationService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name=".owner.event.TitleEvent" />
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Push Notification Service
//Recebe meu push

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
           String text = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
           String action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();

           Intent intent = new Intent(action);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


           String CHANNEL_ID = "MESSAGE";
           NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                  CHANNEL_ID, "Message Notification", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
           getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
           Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                   .setContentTitle(title)
                   .setContentText(text)
                   .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                   .setAutoCancel(true);

           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

           notificationManager.notify(0, notification.build());


           startActivity(intent);


        }
       super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);




    }
```

Quem envia o push

```
public class PushNotificationSend {
    private static String BASE_URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
    private static String SERVER_KEY = "meu server key";

    public static void pushNotification(Context context, String token, String title, String message){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("to",token);
            JSONObject notification = new JSONObject();
            notification.put("title",title);
            notification.put("body",message);
            notification.put("click_action",".owner.event.TitleEvent");

            json.put("notification",notification);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.v("respose",response.toString());

                }

            },  new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    params.put("Authorization", "key="+SERVER_KEY);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }



    }


}
```